# Unable to read the response from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have an ajax function and I place the response into a `div` using `html()`.

```
  $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            data:{selected_grades:selected_grades},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#course_tchr_div").html(data);
            }
  });
```

I need to get the values of some elements which are present inside the `data(ajax response)` in another function.For example,there is are checkboxes with class `course_checkbox_all`.
When I tried to get the element like following,its returning null values

```
console.log($('input.course_checkbox_all').map(function(){return this.value;}).get());
```

Comment: you did net set the data type like `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @Pekka I have put datatype to html,then also I am unable to get the data

Comment: Can you provide the url? Is it a php script with json output? If yes use dataType: "json" in your ajax call. Are you sure you arrive in the success function? Use alert methods in success and error to start investigating where it stops.

Comment: Its php script,I am getting the response correctlyand I have created click functions using on() for some elements inside the response.@gotye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have put the dynamic html response to a specific div, now you want to get the specific element in another function, so you can make a selector with the static parent id which is `course_tchr_div`, you can use `.find()` to get the specific element:

```
    var elems = $('#course_tchr_div').find('input.course_checkbox_all').map(function(){
                    return this.value;
                }).get();
    console.log(elems);
```

Comment: I need the response of ajax in another function.@Jai.

Comment: @Techy you can pass the data to that function then like  `yourfunc(data)`.

Comment: I have put $(document) instead of $(data),then also its getting null values

Comment: Then also I am getting null responses.I think since I used html() to include the response,its not added to DOM.

Comment: Can you update your question to see what is the other function where you need it? That should be called after ajax response. because ajax has async nature.

Comment: I got it now.Thanks for your help